# How to avoid running out of memory in ParallelMap?

Tags: parallelization, memory

I am mapping a function over a list of length 77237.

```
ParallelMap[AnalyzeZernikeRecord,records]
```

The result of each function application is just a list of 12 numbers. Each list item should take about the same amount of time and memory. I have 384 GBytes of physical memory and 16 cores. ParallelMap gets about halfway though the list and dies from lack of memory. Will any of the options (e.g. Method or "ItemsPerEvaluation") help with this? The documentation does not discuss memory implications.

Because `records` itself consumes 87 Mbytes, I first used

```
SetSharedVariable[records]
```

In response to suggestions I tried dividing the problem into 6 parts:

```
parts = Partition[records, UpTo[12873]];

res = ParallelMap[AnalyzeZernikeRecord, #] & /@ parts;
```

That also died, despite finishing the first part. I will now try

```
res1 = ParallelMap[AnalyzeZernikeRecord, parts[[1]]];
Put[res1, "res1"]
```

That worked, but when finished Activity Monitor showed that the 16 kernels were still alive, and using 240 GBytes. To clear the memory and allow the second part to complete I did as follows:

```
CloseKernels[]
LaunchKernels[]
res2 = ParallelMap[AnalyzeZernikeRecord, parts[[2]]];
Put[res2, "res2"]
```

Here is the workaround (hack) that finally got me all the way though.

```
res = Table[(
   tmp = ParallelMap[AnalyzeZernikeRecord, parts[[k]]];
   PutAppend[tmp, "res01"];
   CloseKernels[];
   LaunchKernels[];
   tmp
   ), {k, Length[parts]}]
```

I would still like to know whether there is a more elegant solution through use of options.

Comment: What are you currently using as your Method for ParallelMap?

Comment: Can you create a reproducible (but _minimal_) example? BTW do not use SetSharedVariable here.

Comment: I understand that this might not be the ideal solution, but does it actually work if you split `records` in two-three pieces and do the operation in multiple steps? I ask to ascertain whether it is one of the values in `records` that causes trouble, rather than the `ParallelMap` itself.

Comment: I am not specifying a method.

Comment: @marcoB I did try this and it seems to be working. We shall see if it gets to the end.

Comment: Parallel functions make a copy of data array under evaluation for each kernel. Thus, you pay memory for performance.

Comment: Also set $HistoryLength=0 in a new kernel may help.

Comment: @josh Since the output is only five numbers after each evaluation, I would not think that would make much difference.

Comment: @Rom38 But it succeeds in getting through one iteration with 16 kernels. It is only in subsequent iterations that memory gets filled. Clearly something is being retained in memory, but what?

Comment: PS: See edits above for my current work-around.

Comment: @abwatson, the parallelization in your last case works just inside the `ParallelMap`. So, relaunching kernels you just clean memory from the previous steps of the cycle. As all threads have a bit different evaluation time, the generic approach requires individual copy of data for each thread (because generally it can change the own piece of data on the way).

Comment: @Rom38 Is there a way to achieve the same result (cleaning out memory between evaluations) in a more elegant way, e.g. through options?

Comment: @abwatson, There is not a way using the built-in parallel functions. They use an internal memory usage mechanism.  The most effective workaround, as for me, is manual splitting of an array to the appropriate size pieces and usage of the `ParalleXXX` for them. Or you can write the own parallel routine..